# Trouble installing Chrome using wine on Linux

Tags: google-chrome, linux-mint, wine, winetricks

As some of google chrome's dependencies for Linux are unable to be met (libstdc++6 and lsb-base), I've been unable to update it, which bothers me.  So I've tried to install Google Chrome for Windows.  I have installed wine (version 1.6.1) and it seems to be working.  In addition, I've gotten winetricks.  I have 64-bit Linux Mint 13 and have gotten the standalone Windows installer for 64 bit systems.  After running `wine ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe`, I got a ton of `err`s and `fixme`s.  The Chrome installer window said that the version of Windows I was using was unsupported.  I'm not sure if the console log will help, and sorry this post is so long.

The console log:

```
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x1801210f, 0x13fb00, {9b18bff9-915e-4cc1-9c3e-f4ac112cb36c}, 1, 0x180bc65c, (null), (null), 0x13fb18,): stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fadc,0x00000001,0x33faf8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000280, 00000001): partial stub.
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fa7c,0x00000001,0x33fa98) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:file:MoveFileWithProgressW MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH unimplemented
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x1801210f, 0x13f960, {9b18bff9-915e-4cc1-9c3e-f4ac112cb36c}, 1, 0x180bc65c, (null), (null), 0x13f978,): stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fadc,0x00000001,0x33faf8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000280, 00000001): partial stub.
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fa7c,0x00000001,0x33fa98) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
err:service:validate_context_handle Access denied - handle created with access 1, needed 4
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
err:service:validate_context_handle Access denied - handle created with access 1, needed 4
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids 0: stub
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_ITaskScheduler_Activate Partial stub always returning COR_E_FILENOTFOUND
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_IPersistFile_Save (0x14c59c, (nil), 1): stub
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_ITaskScheduler_Activate Partial stub always returning COR_E_FILENOTFOUND
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33f1fc,0x00000001,0x33f218) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_IPersistFile_Save (0x14c734, (nil), 1): stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x1801210f, 0x13f960, {9b18bff9-915e-4cc1-9c3e-f4ac112cb36c}, 1, 0x180bc65c, (null), (null), 0x13f978,): stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fadc,0x00000001,0x33faf8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000280, 00000001): partial stub.
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fa7c,0x00000001,0x33fa98) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids 0: stub
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {0f87369f-a4e5-4cfc-bd3e-73e6154572dd} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {0f87369f-a4e5-4cfc-bd3e-73e6154572dd} could be created for context 0x1
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_ITaskScheduler_Activate Partial stub always returning COR_E_FILENOTFOUND
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_ITaskScheduler_Delete 0x17dee0, L"GoogleUpdateTask": stub
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {0f87369f-a4e5-4cfc-bd3e-73e6154572dd} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {0f87369f-a4e5-4cfc-bd3e-73e6154572dd} could be created for context 0x1
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_ITaskScheduler_Activate Partial stub always returning COR_E_FILENOTFOUND
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_ITaskScheduler_Delete 0x17dee0, L"GoogleUpdateTaskMachine": stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x1801210f, 0x13f778, {9b18bff9-915e-4cc1-9c3e-f4ac112cb36c}, 1, 0x180bc65c, (null), (null), 0x13f790,): stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fadc,0x00000001,0x33faf8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000280, 00000001): partial stub.
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fa7c,0x00000001,0x33fa98) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:userenv:GetProfileType 0x33fd9c
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:netapi32:NetGetJoinInformation Semi-stub (null) 0x33f6e0 0x33f6dc
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33f49c,0x00000001,0x33f4b8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L"gupdate"): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000000,(nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x82e730,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (0xcafe4242) stub
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids 0: stub
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x1801210f, 0x13f778, {9b18bff9-915e-4cc1-9c3e-f4ac112cb36c}, 1, 0x180bc65c, (null), (null), 0x13f790,): stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fadc,0x00000001,0x33faf8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000280, 00000001): partial stub.
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fa7c,0x00000001,0x33fa98) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:userenv:GetProfileType 0x33fd9c
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33f90c,0x00000001,0x33f928) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x1801210f, 0x140418, {9b18bff9-915e-4cc1-9c3e-f4ac112cb36c}, 1, 0x180bc65c, (null), (null), 0x140430,): stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fadc,0x00000001,0x33faf8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000280, 00000001): partial stub.
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fa7c,0x00000001,0x33fa98) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:netapi32:NetGetJoinInformation Semi-stub (null) 0x33fa48 0x33fa44
fixme:winhttp:WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl discovery via DHCP not supported
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x1801210f, 0x13fd10, {9b18bff9-915e-4cc1-9c3e-f4ac112cb36c}, 1, 0x180bc65c, (null), (null), 0x13fd28,): stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fadc,0x00000001,0x33faf8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000280, 00000001): partial stub.
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fa7c,0x00000001,0x33fa98) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity ((nil),-1,(nil),(nil),6,3,(nil),64,(nil)) - stub!
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x1801210f, 0x13f778, {9b18bff9-915e-4cc1-9c3e-f4ac112cb36c}, 1, 0x180bc65c, (null), (null), 0x13f790,): stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fadc,0x00000001,0x33faf8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000280, 00000001): partial stub.
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fa7c,0x00000001,0x33fa98) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:userenv:GetProfileType 0x33fd9c
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L"gupdate"): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000000,(nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x82e730,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (0xcafe4242) stub
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids 0: stub
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids 0: stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x1801210f, 0x13f778, {9b18bff9-915e-4cc1-9c3e-f4ac112cb36c}, 1, 0x180bc65c, (null), (null), 0x13f790,): stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fadc,0x00000001,0x33faf8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000280, 00000001): partial stub.
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fa7c,0x00000001,0x33fa98) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:userenv:GetProfileType 0x33fd9c
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids 0: stub
fixme:ole:CoGetClassObject CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER not supported
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {4eb61bac-a3b6-4760-9581-655041ef4d69} could be created for context 0x17
fixme:netapi32:NetGetJoinInformation Semi-stub (null) 0x33f9a0 0x33f99c
err:ole:CoSetProxyBlanket -- failed with 0x80004002
fixme:advapi:ImpersonateLoggedOnUser (0xa0)
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x93e4ec,0x00000001,0x93e508) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x93e5bc,0x00000001,0x93e5d8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x93e47c,0x00000001,0x93e498) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x93e63c,0x00000001,0x93e658) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33f2cc,0x00000001,0x33f2e8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x1801210f, 0x140508, {9b18bff9-915e-4cc1-9c3e-f4ac112cb36c}, 1, 0x180bc65c, (null), (null), 0x140520,): stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fadc,0x00000001,0x33faf8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000280, 00000001): partial stub.
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fa7c,0x00000001,0x33fa98) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:netapi32:NetGetJoinInformation Semi-stub (null) 0x33fa48 0x33fa44
fixme:winhttp:WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl discovery via DHCP not supported
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids 0: stub
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids 0: stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33f4ec,0x00000001,0x33f508) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fa1c,0x00000001,0x33fa38) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x1801210f, 0x13f960, {9b18bff9-915e-4cc1-9c3e-f4ac112cb36c}, 1, 0x180bc65c, (null), (null), 0x13f978,): stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fadc,0x00000001,0x33faf8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000280, 00000001): partial stub.
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fa7c,0x00000001,0x33fa98) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids 0: stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x1801210f, 0x13f898, {9b18bff9-915e-4cc1-9c3e-f4ac112cb36c}, 1, 0x180bc65c, (null), (null), 0x13f8b0,): stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fadc,0x00000001,0x33faf8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000280, 00000001): partial stub.
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33fa7c,0x00000001,0x33fa98) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids 0: stub
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {0f87369f-a4e5-4cfc-bd3e-73e6154572dd} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {0f87369f-a4e5-4cfc-bd3e-73e6154572dd} could be created for context 0x1
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_ITaskScheduler_Activate Partial stub always returning COR_E_FILENOTFOUND
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_ITaskScheduler_Delete 0x17dee0, L"GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore": stub
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {0f87369f-a4e5-4cfc-bd3e-73e6154572dd} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {0f87369f-a4e5-4cfc-bd3e-73e6154572dd} could be created for context 0x1
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_ITaskScheduler_Activate Partial stub always returning COR_E_FILENOTFOUND
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_ITaskScheduler_Delete 0x17dee0, L"GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA": stub
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_ITaskScheduler_Enum 0x17dee0, 0x33fc70: stub
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_ITaskScheduler_Enum 0x17dee0, 0x33fc70: stub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Open `winecfg` and set the Windows version to 7.  Wine defaults to XP, which many applications don't support anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Install native Chromium, is there a reason you need the Windows version of Chrome? Chromium is just as compatible and is available on both Arch and Debian.
On Debian, I think the command to install it is:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium
```

And on Arch I just use Octopi, Chromium is compatible with most Chrome plugins and the UI is identical.